# How can multiple threads maintain reference to an instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, this

The client is presented with a class called `Scheduler` which schedules alarms at certain intervals. To do this, I have a method `setAlarm` in the class which adds alarms to a Priority Queue and does a `notify()` to let a `Timer` procedure know it's time to wake up and process what is on top of the queue.

Below is an example of a basic implementation-

```
class Scheduler {

    synchronized public void setAlarm(Date date) {
        notify();
    }

    synchronized private void alarmTimer() {
        while (true) {
             wait();
             System.out.println("Alarm Triggered");
        }
    }
```

Now I would need the `Timer` procedure to run on another thread, since it will be waiting till it receives a notification or till the time is up. But the client should be unaware there are two threads. As far as the client is concerned, it will just do a `schedulerInstance.setAlarm(myDate)` and it should be handled.

So the `Scheduler` must create a separate thread for `alarmTimer()`. How would I call alarmTimer from this new thread while still referencing the right `this` object? What is the correct way to handle a situation where I want multiple threads to maintain reference to the original `Scheduler` instance so that `wait()` and `notify()` work?

Comment: Since Java 5 there is  [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which you can use for the job.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one approach:

1. extend Thread
2. synchronize rather on `this` than on method level
3. start your thread & keep your reference on `this` ...

---

```
 class Scheduler extends java.lang.Thread {

  public void setAlarm(Date date) {
    synchronized(this) {
      this.notify();
    }
  }

  private void alarmTimer() {
    this.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    synchronized(this) {
      while (true) {
         this.wait();
         System.out.println("Alarm Triggered");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Every other approach is thinkable, where you can keep the reference on the waiting object between alarm start&stop. (`anyObject.wait()` and `anyObject.notify()`)

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to extend Thread? Isn't the recommended method to use ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: @sbhatla : no, it is "not that bad practice" (..to extend thread... since shown in many tutorials/taught in school). `ThreadPoolExecutor` doesn't conflict with extending Thread, but it is rather a (proper) "container" to execute & manage (multiple) threads.